# Calling the HomePage and having it display a PartialView (ie.ResetPassword) from external link

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Imagine the ForgotPassword sent an email with a link to Recover the password. Ideally we want the RecoverPassword to be a PartialView and it has to run inside the HomePage itself.

The external link passes a GUID.

**QUESTIONS:**
1) What's the right way to tell the Home Page to display the Partial View only on this specific case?
2) What would be the URL link look like?
3) What would the HomePage Index Controller look like so that it would also handle the possibility of a ResetPassword external link request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something simple like have a query string. for example www.yoururl.com/index?showresetpassword=true

Then inside your view you can add an if statement to render the partial view or not. If you need it inside of the controller I suggest you have the parameter as a nullable bool. Something like

```
public ActionResult Index(bool? showresetpassword)
```

Make it nullable so that if it is not inside of the url you will not have any isssues.

Comment: Interesting, i'll try that later today and let you know.

Comment: works well ...i just put the value on the ViewBag.PartialView and now I can decide what partial view to show on HomePage load ..or the default one. Thanks a lot !!!